# Is there a way to use a parameter from systemctl status to either continue or break code?

Tags: linux, boto3

Is there a parameter I can take from `systemctl status ...` in order to confirm that a software is running and allow the code to continue? I have the `systemctl status` command running but with no way to confirm the status. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example check auditd service using systemctl

`sudo systemctl status auditd.service | egrep running; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "Audit Service is running" else echo "Audit service is not running"; fi`

Using single line command you can check service is running or not and can continue with other stuffs.